# Get the TTY which sent a signal in Perl

Tags: perl, signals, tty

I have a Perl script which runs as a background process on an e-mail server and attempts to detect compromised e-mail accounts through various checks on the queue and log files.  I added a handler for the USR1 signal which causes the script to print some information about itself while it's running.  This works great if I start the script in the background and then send the USR1 signal, like so:

```
./myscript.pl &
kill -USR1 (PID)
```

The problem is, if I exit that shell session and then connect in again, I can't get any output when I use the `kill -USR1` command anymore because the TTY associated with STDOUT for the script is gone.

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to get the TTY of the user or shell process which sent a signal in Perl, and then direct output back to the TTY instead of STDOUT.  I tried using `POSIX::ttyname(1)` in the signal handler, but it returns the TTY of the script's STDOUT (which is an empty value in this case), not the TTY of the user who sent the USR1 signal.

I saw in the Perldoc for POSIX that `POSIX::sigaction` will give the PID and UID of the process which generated the signal, but I don't know if there's a good way to get the TTY name from that information in Perl.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Why not to use some kind of a log file to capture the script's output: `./myscript.pl > some.log &` and then monitor it with `tail -f some.log` command from any TTY you like?

Comment: That's actually my fallback plan.  Have the signal handler write out the information to a file rather than a TTY.  The information I want to get from it is stuff like uptime, number of messages processed, etc., so it would be better if I could get this information on demand rather than have the script log it periodically at some interval.  I guess I might need to write a shell script to send the USR1 signal, then `cat` the output file before deleting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is the one proposed by nab in a comment to your question: just log your output to a file (possibly in your $SIG{USR1} handler), and then monitor that.  You could even overwrite it each time you get a SIGUSR1.

Another solution, which I've got running, is to create a socket handler.  This gets a bit more convoluted, unless you're willing to use a bunch of modules.  My solution is to use [AnyEvent](http://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent) + [Coro](http://metacpan.org/module/Coro).  I put the main work in one Coro thread, start up my [AnyEvent::Socket](http://metacpan.org/module/AnyEvent%3a%3aSocket)::tcp_server(s) (socket and/or tcp port number), and, on connection, do what I need to do (in my case, create a bunch of threads, in your case just output the details like you do in your $SIG{USR1} handler, and close the connection).

Real code:

```
AnyEvent::Socket::tcp_server "unix/", "/tmp/cbstats.sock", sub {
    my $fh = shift;
    $fh->binmode(':utf8');
    $fh = unblock $fh;

    $self->handle_connection($fh, @_);

};
```

And then, because mine is interactive, I run `socat readline /tmp/cbstats.sock`.  In your case, you could just do `socat stdout /tmp/your.socket` any time you wanted the output.  (Use filesystem permissions to restrict/allow who can see this data.)

There's a little bit to concern yourself here - you'll need to stop using sleep() (or use the Coro version) so that you can receive requests on the socket.  But, to be honest, it's been mostly minimal.  I have, however, switched my server over to using AnyEvent timers, then I don't even need to worry about sleeping.  After that, I smooshed multiple servers together on their own timers, and it has all worked fairly well.

Good luck.

Comment: I think the output file solution is what I'll end up using.  I'll have the signal handler write the output to a file, and then I'll just write a shell script to send the USR1 signal and dump the contents of the file to the user.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The two main problems with what you're asking are that

1. The TTY is gone/deleted once the invoking shell terminates
   On my Linux system, the effect is similar to what happens if you open/redirect STDOUT to a file and then *unlink* that file.  You're not getting that output device back unless you play awful, awful tricks in `/proc`
2. Signals don't carry the TTY of the sender
   Neither by [minimal specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/signal.h.html) nor by [implementations which extend the spec](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)

So, I'd suggest you either run the utility under a terminal multiplexor like [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), or redirect STDOUT to some other output that you can check from another terminal ... like a file, or the system log, or a database, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping to avoid using screen, etc., to make it a behave more like a daemon and seem a little more "native" (if that makes sense).  I may need to explore that option, though.

Comment: @Dave, daemons often log to logging subsystems, FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

What's your OS? `ps(1)` can output the controlling tty for any process id. On Linux, `/proc/<pid>/fd/1` and `/proc/<pid>/fd/2` are symbolic links to the terminal or files that a process's output streams are attached to.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the OS is Solaris 10 (SPARC).  I tried using `POSIX::sigaction` with the SA_SIGINFO flag set on the corresponding `SigAction` object, but Solaris doesn't pass the pid and uid (or anything else) to the handler, even with the SA_SIGINFO flag set.